# Avoiding nesting Promise (eslint warning)

Tags: javascript, eslint

Suppose we have 3 parameters : `c1, c2 & c3` and a function `f1`.

Now we want to write a function as below :

```
fun() {

 return Promise.resolve (f1(c1))
  .then (abc => {
   if(abc) {
    return Promise.resolve (f1(c2))
     .then (abc1 => {
      if(abc1) {
       return Promise.resolve (f1(c3))
        .then(abc2 => {
         doSomething
        });
      else
       return true;
      }
   else
    return true;
   });
});
```

Can we implement the same by avoiding nesting promise ?

Comment: EsLint is pretty wrong here. If you have nested `if` statements, you also must nest your promises.

Comment: That code is not valid, please fix it.

Comment: With `async/await` https://jsfiddle.net/50xdL8js/